# Vue 3: Append to child component prop

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3, prop

I am creating a little puzzle game to learn Vue 3 and got stuck, when trying to append values to an array in a child component.

This is the parent:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <Puzzle :guess="puzzleGuess" />
  </div>
</template>
```

This is the child component 'Puzzle':

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <img :src="require(`@/assets/${imgPath}`)" alt="Puzzle image" class="puzzleImage" >
        </div>
        <div class="row puzzleIcon" :key="i" v-for="(char, i) in word">
            <span v-if="hasGuessedChar(char)">{{char}}</span>
            <span v-else>
                <i class="large material-icons">remove</i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Puzzle',
        props: {
            word: Array,
            imgPath: String,
            guess: Array,
        },
        methods: {
            hasGuessedChar(char) {
                if(char == '') return false;

                if(this.guess.indexOf(char) > -1) return true;
           
                return false;
            }
        }
    }    
</script>
```

Basically, I would like to push a char to the `guess` array property of the child component, whenever the prop `puzzleGuess` is updated in the parent component. With the current posted code, I just keep on overwriting the `guess` variable instead of appending to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by the suggested answer from @MohKoma, I arrived at this solution (unsure if it is the same as @Mohkoma suggested):

Parent component:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <Puzzle :guess="puzzleGuess" />
    <hr />
    <div class="letters-container">
        <Letters @clickLetter="clickLetter" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>      
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    Letters,
    Puzzle
  },
  data() {
    return{          
      puzzleGuess: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clickLetter(letter) {
      this.puzzleGuess.push(letter.val.toLowerCase());
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

...and child component remains unchanged:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="row puzzleIcon" :key="i" v-for="(char, i) in word">
            <span v-if="hasGuessedChar(char)">{{char}}</span>
            <span v-else>
                <i class="large material-icons">remove</i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Puzzle',
        props: {
            word: Array,
            guess: Array,
        },
        methods: {
            hasGuessedChar(char) {
                if(char == '') return false;

                if(this.guess.indexOf(char) > -1) return true;
                
                return false;
            }
        }
    }    
</script>
```

So basically, instead of trying to push a value to the array in the child component, I push the value to a local array and then pass that array down to the child component

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, You must know that `guess` and `puzzleGuess` are the same.
So pushing something in the child component or watching it will lead to infinite loop errors in most cases.

The solution if you're looking to add `char` only if an event happened in the parent component is to create local data in the child ex: `loaclGuess`.
Fill it with `guess` on load and set a watcher for `guess`.

But try this in the Child component

```
data() {
   return {
      loaclGuess: this.guess
   }
}
```

Then

```
pushCharToGuess(char) {

    if(char == '') return false;

    // Important has to stop it to avoid empty loop 
    if(!this. loaclGuess.includes(char)) return true;

    // Push char
    this.loaclGuess.push(char);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input - it led me to a solution which works for me. I am unsure if I understand your solution completely, so I will post my working solution.